# Need to replace Shimano FD-M191

Tags: derailleur-front

I need to replace a rusted up Shimano FD-M191 front derailleur.  This is the original equipment on my 2010 Fuji Absolute 3.0, which has 3 gears in front and 8 in back.  Acera SL-M310 rapid fire shifters. Seems like FD-M590 for FD-M360 might work?  So many models.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of criteria when selecting a front derailleur. The number of gears must match. You need an 8 speed triple with a clamp diameter to match your frame. This is assuming that your derailleur clamps to the seat post. This is where things can get complicated. Some clamps come with an adapter to fit more than one size seat post. The next option is a high or low mount clamp. This is determined by the location of the clamp in relation to the actual part that does the derailing. Another criteria is top pull or bottom cable pull. This is another area where they make units that will work either way depending on how the cable is routed. I have access to an 24 speed Absolute DX. It has a 31.8mm/high mount clamp and uses a bottom pull design.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [specs for your current FD-M191](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano/FD-M191-3.html) front derailleur.   Your choice of replacement should have similar specs if you want to just change the derailleur.  Important points to look for in a replacement are that it's a mountain derailleur for a triple chainwheel that can handle the size of your large chainwheel (tooth count is the unit of measure). The M191 is used with either a 44 or 48 tooth count large ring.  Based on the [Fuji provided specs](https://archive.fujibikes.com/2010/Fuji/absolute-30-usa) for your bike you have 48-38-28 tooth crankset. The new derailleur must be designed to accomodate a 48 tooth large ring of a triple crankset.  Another important and related factor is the tooth difference between the large and middle ring. Note there's a 10 tooth difference between middle and large ring, and this is a pretty important spec for the new derailleur to have for good shifting.

Next, in order to only have to change out the front derailleur, we need to have the new derailleur mount the same as the M191 , which is a band clamp derailleur (a correctly sized clamp band around the seat tube).  These bands come in different sizes or come equipped with the largest band and shims to be able to fit smaller tubed frames.  Your Fuji takes a band clamp size of 31.8 mm.  Next thing that needs to be the same as the M191 is the type of pull--the direction from which the cable comes from and the direction it's pulled--that moves the derailleur.  Choices are top pull, bottom pull, or dual pull (which is what the M191 is). Your next derailleur needn't be dual pull, but must pull the same way you're pulling the M191 now.

A final factor that will need confirmation is that the new derailleur supports a 47.5 mm chainline.  Chain line is a subject for another discussion and I minimize the relevance to your situation based on your front drivetrain being a mountain triple with essentially the largest tooth counts available  in mountain biking/trekking.  So that information pretty much infers your chainline being 47.5 mm.

To summerize,  your replacement front derailleur must be a mountain triple, band-on (correct size band or able to be shimmed down to correct size), top/bottom pull (correct way or dual  pull), capable of handling a 48 tooth large chainring with a 10 tooth difference to the middle chainwheel.  You have 8 gears in back so the ideal would be a front derailleur for 6, 7, 8 speed systems.  However, in practice, this is far less a concern than the above information as a front derailleur marketed for a 9 or even 10 speed system will work just fine if the aforementioned parameters are satisfied.